# How can turn off MahApps Button transparent effect?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have a MahApps button as follows:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Button.Chromeless}" Foreground="Blue" Content="{icon:Modern Kind=Add}"></Button>
```

I don't want it to have a transparency effect, but I don't know how to do it.
I tried to set the `Foreground` property and so on, but to no avail.

[image: Button with tranparenccy effect.]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the `Background`. The `Foreground` only affects the glyph or text content.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Button.Chromeless}" Foreground="Blue" Background="Red" Content="{iconPacks:Modern Kind=Add}"/>
```

Alternatively, use any of the other `Button` styles that already have a background set.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Button.Flat}" Foreground="Blue" Content="{iconPacks:Modern Kind=Add}"/>
<Button Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Button.Square}" Foreground="Blue" Content="{iconPacks:Modern Kind=Add}"/>
```